# react-native android error 404

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

can anyone tell me why im getting this error :

my code is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
 AppRegistry,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View,
 TextInput,
 Image,
 LinkingIOS,
 Navigator,
 WebView

} from 'react-native';

export default class  ReactNativeReactWebview extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

    <WebView 

      source={require('./index.html')}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
    />


);
 }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('reactAndroid',()=>ReactNativeReactWebview);
```

my app run good in emulator but get error in command line ....the error in this pic :

[my error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrC2E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers try to get the favicon by default in the `favicon.ico` path. If your WebView is rendering as expected, I'd say it should be OK.

Comment: i dont have a favicon.ico path in my project file !!

Comment: That's the reason why you are getting the error. The browser is trying to get the favicon and is failing, hence the packager returns a "file not found" (404). But this will not affect your WebView in any way, so it is safe to leave it as it is.

Comment: thnx you alot @martinarroyo  :)